# how to have sketchflow style controls in Windows Phone8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, sketchflow

I liked the sketchflow sketchy styles in Sketchflow app. I wanted to use them in the WindowsPhone 8 application. I looked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145403/can-you-use-sketchflow-controls-styles-in-a-wpf-application) but couldn't able use the answer without any errors.

Is there any best way to do it?

Comment: you're going to have to provide more detail if you want any help. What have you tried? What errors did you get?

Comment: i tried to add Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.SketchControls.dll as reference to my WP8 project to get those sketchy controls...but i am getting error like - this reference can't be added to this project.

Comment: I think that's your problem - they're not WP8 controls, they're WPF controls

Comment: i know the problem, that's y i am asking here for help...

Comment: you can't use them because they are wpf controls, that's the point